Matching text-number to text-number in Excel?
I have a spreadsheet with two tabs.  Tab #1, the main tab, has a list of UPC codes and quantities of items by direct count.  Tab #2 is a reference sheet of UPC codes and item quantities as drawn from an inventory database and output to a CSV.  I want to use VLOOKUP from Tab 1 to find the matching UPC in Tab 2, then bring the 'database' inventory count from Tab 2 back into Tab 1 so I can compare them directly.
According to Excel, the UPCs in both tabs are "number stored as text".  Tab #1 has just the UPC.  Tab #2, for reasons I won't go into, has the UPC with a leading and a trailing space.  I know that the UPC from Tab 1 has a match in Tab 2 -- I can find the match with a direct search -- but VLOOKUP absolutely refuses to see the match.  I've tried using TEXT().  I've tried using VALUE().  I've tried adding a leading and trailing space to the main UPC value.  I've tried trimming the leading and trailing space from the reference value.  I even tried converting both to the same "custom" format.  The only thing that seems to find the match is to do what Excel wants me to and convert both UPC values to numbers, but that loses the leading zero that many UPCs have, and risks getting false matches.
I can understand VLOOKUP failing if the lookup value is a number and the reference range is full of text values, or vice versa.  But I can't for the life of me understand why it fails when BOTH values are "number stored as text".
How can I get this lookup to work without having to convert the UPCs to numbers?

Update: Bugdrown's comment provided a solution: use CLEAN(TRIM()) to clean up both UPCs, and now the VLOOKUP() formula finds matches as it should.  Thanks!

Hard to help, pls. provide the workbook. Description is clear enough, but data created based on it can be different from the original.

You might try using use XLOOKUP() for its flexibility, instead of VLOOKUP(). You might also try nesting both your search criteria and your lookup range inside CLEAN(TRIM()), in case you're dealing with nonprinting characters.

I think that you need to somehow sanitize your data before doing advanced operations. It is my preferred way of doing. E.g., use a third tab where you have a copy of the data in the second tab, minus the extra spaces, the numbers formatted as desired etc. After that, the rest of the formulas will work better. Otherwise, garbage in, garbage out.
